# Как передавать поток изображений как online-видео?

Tags: javascript

Я получаю live изображение с камеры Nikon и в бесконечном цикле передаю через вебсокет клиенту в src=....
Это неправильно и работает с сильным запаздыванием картинки. Как правильно передавать поток изображений как online-видео?

Comment: Какое запаздывание для вас приемлемо?

Comment: И какое изображение вы получаете с камеры, в каком формате, разрешении, размере, качестве?